# $_FILES undefined index error como resolver

Tags: php, jquery, upload, imagem

Ao fazer o upload de uma imagem recebo o erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: imagem in C:\Apache24\htdocs\change_photo.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: imagem in C:\Apache24\htdocs\change_photo.php on line 10

Chamada:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                
                $('#imagem').live('change',function(){
                    var url1 = "change_photo.php";
                    var email1 = "<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>";
                    var fileVal=document.getElementById("imagem");
                    var fakeFile = fileVal.value;
                    $.post(url1,{postemail1:email1,foto:fakeFile},
                        function(result) {
                        $("#visualizar").html(result); // Só pra verificar retorno
                    });
                
                });
            }) 
</script>
```

Form:

```
<form id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="change_photo.php">
        Foto
        <input type="file" id="imagem" name="imagem" /> 
    </form>
```

Change_photo.php:

```
 include('conexao.php');
 $pasta = "fotos/";

 /* formatos de imagem permitidos */ 
 echo $_POST['foto'];

 $permitidos = array(".jpg",".jpeg",".gif",".png", ".bmp");

    $name = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];

    $error = $_FILES['imagem']['error'];
```

Alguém saberia me dizer onde está o problema?

Comment: precisa ser upload utilizando jquery? o erro creio que está ao fazer esse `$.post` via jquery. Tente apenas com php e html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está passando o valor do file para um post "comum" nesta função ajax. O input file tem um comportamento próprio, por isso tem o `enctype="multipart/form-data"` no form. Basta dar um submit normalmente que o valor será populado no `$_FILE` e com isso deve funcionar.

Comment: Fiz o que você disse: incluí um submit e tirei a parte do ajax... e funcionou ! Muito obrigado pela ajuda